# Chelation-controlled aldol: why is the α substituent pseudo-axial?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, stereoselectivity, aldol-reaction

In this Mukaiyama aldol reaction, taken from a 1999 paper by D.A. Evans,<sup>1</sup> when $\ce{TiCl4}$ was used as the Lewis acid catalyst, the aldehyde **4a** formed a chelated intermediate whereas **4b** did not (due to the bulk of the TBS group). This was demonstrated by the stereochemistry of the product. Aldehyde **4a** produced a *syn*:*anti* ratio of 3:97, whereas aldehyde **4b** led to a ratio of 93:7:

[image: Reaction scheme]

The **chelated intermediate** which aldehyde **4a** goes through is a standard six-membered ring with a half-chair conformation. Perplexingly, the α-methyl group has to be placed pseudo-axial instead of pseudo-equatorial (or else the *syn* aldol product will be obtained):

[image: Conformational analysis]

Ordinarily, substituents would adopt a pseudo-equatorial position in the dominant conformer. Why is this an exception?

**Reference**

1. Evans, D. A.; Allison, B. D.; Yang, M. G. Chelate-controlled carbonyl addition reactions. The exceptional chelating ability of dimethylaluminum chloride and methylaluminum dichloride. *Tetrahedron Lett.* **1999,** *40* (24), 4457–4460. [DOI: 10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00739-X](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00739-X).

Answer (score 5):

Having the methyl group *psuedo*-axial means that when the nucleophile approaches, the transitiation state is chair-like. The energy penalty for having the methyl group initially in the less favourable position is compensated for the low energy TS.

The ring-flipped version, in which the methyl group is *psuedo*-equatorial, would open via a high energy twisted TS (the opposite of the argument presented above, i.e. the low energy conformation of the starting material doesn't compensate for the high energy of the twisted TS).

[image]

Looking at the Evans' paper specifically, the TS he draws has an addition isopropyl group on the beta-carbon, which *is* equatorial (this would further stabilise the starting material, since the isopropyl would be far higher in energy if axial compared to the methyl).

Comment: In your second TS, you can have the nucleophile attack from below, no? And that would give the syn aldol product, but still via a chair TS. [I saw the TS with the iPr group, but he repeated it with a different substrate lacking the iPr group (the one I drew above), and the result was similar.]

Comment: I suppose theres a steric argument, that the nucleophile (in this case a bulky silyl enol ether) doesn't want to approach across the methyl group

Comment: Yeah, I think that was my guess, but I just wasn't super sure about it.